# Expand row in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am using a DataGrid to display some log files, where each cell contains a TextBlock. I need help creating a method to expand a user selected row like this:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5649690/StackOverflow%20-%20Do%20not%20delete/Expand%20row%20in%20wpf%20datagrid/Do%20want.png]

This is my code right now. It is based on the index of the clicked row:

```
DataGridRow testrow = (DataGridRow)logBrowserDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);

logBrowserDataGrid.UpdateLayout();
logBrowserDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(logBrowserDataGrid.Items[index]);

testrow = (DataGridRow)logBrowserDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
testrow.Height = 100;
```

However this creates a weird result:

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5649690/StackOverflow%20-%20Do%20not%20delete/Expand%20row%20in%20wpf%20datagrid/Do%20not%20want%20.png]

Do you know a god way to expand a row based on the index?

Do you know what happens in the weird result i get? It looks like i am expanding a part of the row, and the rest does stretch out. I have also studied it in runtime, and can see that its height is the correct 100, but the ActuallyHeight is still 20.

Additional info:
The default size of the rows are set by the .RowHeight property on the DataGrid. 
I am using the AutoGenerateColumns feature, plus catching the AutogeneratingColumn event to replace the column with a DataGridTemplateColumn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not replace the default DataGridCellTemplate with an Expander to do all that for you?

```
<DataGridColumn>
    <DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding SomeText}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridColum>
```

If you don't like the default Expander look, you can overwrite it's Template to look like a plain TextBlock

As a side note, to stretch and vertically align a DataGridRow, you want to stretch and align the Cell Content, not the Row.

Comment: I like the idea of using the Expander control camouflaged as a TextBlock, however I do not know how to do it, without destroying the functionality of the Expander - I do not want to have the text multiple times (e.g. the first line both in the header and in the expanded area).

Comment: @ChristianOlling You could always set the Visibility of the Header to Collapsed when the Expander is expanded, and WPF will only load one TextBlock or the other. You can find the default templates for WPF controls here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx. I was also just thinking that perhaps you could just add a `Click` event to a `TextBlock` which sets its `TextWrapping` to `Wrap` or `NoWrap`

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an Expander and the functionality was precisely what I wanted, but the look was not however. I have tried restyling the Expander to fit my need, but gave up because of the events I needed to add to it (XamlReader + events was more than my programming skills could handle). But based on Rachels suggestion I made a UserControl with the following content:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MouseUp="StackPanel_MouseUp">
   <TextBlock Name="headerTextBlock" Margin="3,2,3,2" Height="20" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
   <TextBlock Name="textTextBlock" Margin="3,2,3,2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the codebehind I then can handle the event "StackPanel_MouseUp" to change the visibility of the TextBlocks. This control looks and works like I wanted the restyled Expander to do.

Now my xaml string looks like this.

```
string xamlCellTemplateFormat =
         @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                         xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
                         ~local~>
                <local:CustomExpander x:Name=""UserControlTest"" Header=""{Binding Path=~binding~}"" Text=""{Binding Path=~binding~}""/>
           </DataTemplate>";

string xamlCellTemplate = xamlCellTemplateFormat.Replace("~binding~", e.Column.Header.ToString());
xamlCellTemplate = xamlCellTemplate.Replace("~local~", " xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:IS.AppFramework.Windows.LogBrowserWPF;assembly=" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + "\"");
```